# Typescript 5.0, avoid importing .ts as .js files and building project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, transpiler

Is there any way with Typescript 5.0 to both import Typescript modules using the `.ts` extension and have the code transpiled to the `dist` folder?

In our Typescript 5.0 project we are importing our typescript modules using '.js' file extensions, such that:

```
import InvalidValueError from '../errors/InvalidValueError.js'
```

rather than:

```
import InvalidValueError from '../errors/InvalidValueError.ts'
```

We can do the import of the '.ts' file if we add the following to the `compilerOptions`
section `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
  "noEmit": true,
  "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
```

With this we get errors of the form:

> An import path can only end with a '.ts' extension when 'allowImportingTsExtensions' is enabled

The issue here is that while it does allow importing, running `tsc -p .` no longer generates the Javascript files in out `dist` folder.

The reason we are wanting to explicitly import using the '.ts' extension is that it makes more sense the developer to be importing the file as presented on the file system and leaving any further transformation to the transpiler. The opposite would be seen as the 'C' equivalent of including '.o' files, rather than '.h' or '.c' files.

Note, out `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node16",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2020",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ],

  "ts-node": {
    "files": true,
  }
}
```

Comment: @ChrisHeald `allowImportingTsExtensions` requires that `noEmit` be set. The `moduleResolution` should however be `bundler` and your bundler is then responsible for packaging the modules.

Comment: Any recommendations on a bundler and a suggested recipe we could follow?

Comment: Any recommendations on a bundler and a suggested recipe we could follow? Please?